# What is the recommended way to install the binaries built by Cargo for packaging purposes?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

How can I access the generated `foo` binary when I have this in my Cargo.toml?

```
[[bin]]
name = "foo"
path = "src/foo.rs"
```

Ideally I would like to have something which works like

```sh
make install DESTDIR=$(pwd)/i
```

I tried:

- `cargo build --out-dir $(pwd)/i`  --> fails with "error: the `--out-dir` flag is unstable"
- `cargo install --path . --root $(pwd)/i` --> comes near to the result, but it seems to be impossible to set flags like `--release` or its opposite variant (yes, I want the debug binary!)
- `OUT_DIR=$(pwd)/i cargo build`  --> does not seem to have any effect as there is no directory generated

I could dig into the target directory, but there are a lot of unwanted files so globs will not work and I will have to know exactly the artifact name, including automatic suffices like `.a`, `.so`, `.so.1.2.3`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to access binaries built by cargo?

The `cargo install --path . --root $(pwd)/i` is the correct way to specify the destination installation directory.

> but it seems to be impossible to set flags like --release or its opposite variant (yes: I want the debug binary!)

It's possible with the `--debug` flag.

```
cargo install --debug --path . --root $(pwd)/i
```

See [cargo install manual](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-cargo-install/).

Comment: Why ```--root``` ? This flag is not required for me.

Comment: @Sam If `--root` is not specified the package will be installed in the default cargo bin directory (`~/.cargo/bin`) but the OP asked to install in `./i`.